# Small o notation PROOF

Tags: notation, information-theory

It's probably a vey silly question, but I'm confused. 
I should proof the small o notation with lim but i don´t know how

$(\ln n)^a = o(n^b )$
how do i solve this and do i need to proof it for 
$a<b$, $a>b$ or $a=b$ ?

Comment: PLEAS IGNORE Does o(1) simply mean limn→∞f(n)ϵ=0 for some n>N?

Comment: If a function of n is o(1), it means it converges to 0 as n goes to infinity.

Comment: The correct notation is $f(n) = o(g(n))$. Writing equality  $f(n) = o(g(n))$ means that 
$
f(n) 
$
live in set $o(g(n))$. Here,
$$
o(g(n))\mathop{=}^{\mathrm{def}}\left\{f(n): \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0\right\}
$$

Comment: I believe your question is to find the lowest value of $ b> 0 $ such that $(\ln n)^a = o(n^b )$, that is, to find the lowest value of $ b> 0 $ such that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\ln n)^a}{n^b}=0.
$$
Correct?

Comment: "PLEASE IGORE" ... you should be able to edit your own question to delete that part.

Answer (score 1):

I think that $a,b>0$. You have to show that $\frac{( \ln n)^a}{n^b} \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty$. If $t:= \ln n$, then we have to show that

$\frac{t^a}{e^{tb}} \to 0$ as $ t \to \infty$. To this end let $ m \in \mathbb N$ with $m>a$. Then $e^{tb} \ge \frac{t^mb^m}{m!}$, hence

$ 0 \le \frac{t^a}{e^{tb}} \le \frac{t^a}{e^{tb}} \le \frac{m!}{b^m}\frac{1}{t^{m-a}}$

Your turn !

Answer (score 0):

Correct notation is $f(n) = o(g(n))$. Writing equality $f(n) = o(g(n))$ means  that 
$
f(n) 
$
live in set $o(g(n))$. Here,
$$
o(g(n))\mathop{=}^{\mathrm{def}}\left\{f(n): \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0\right\}
$$
I believe your question is to find the lowest value of $ b> 0 $ such that $(\ln n)^a = o(n^b )$ for $a>0$, that is, to find the lowest value of $ b> 0 $ such that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\ln n)^a}{n^b}=0.
$$
Correct? To prove this you should use the fact that for all $c>0$ we have 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} n^c/e^n=0.
$$

Comment: The problem is they dont want the lowest b > 0  .
The question is just if f(n)=o(g(n)m
we should prove it with limes but i dont have a clue how :/